# How do I convert Mathematica code into Matlab?

Tags: matlab, syntax, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I'm just starting to learn MatLab.
This is what I'd like to convert into MatLab code:

http://postimg.org/image/jqdvcrbod/

1. Since a lot of my variables are functions or other variables, does that mean that when I write them as functions in MatLab I have to save each of the functions as a separate file? Is there any other way? I don't want to end up with a million separate files, but as of right now, if I write more then one function in the editor, it starts getting confused and doesn't recognize the second function.
2. Also, is there a way to use actual symbols (like the square root symbol instead of writing "sqrt()") like in Mathematica? I feel like long equations (like the last one) are easier on the eye that way, but that's purely aesthetics.
3. Is there a way to have MatLab output unassigned variables? Like in Mathematica, if I have y(x) = 2x, if i don't put anything for x, it just outputs 2x.

Comment: Try dividing your question into smaller pieces. 2) for example has nothing to do with Mathematica.

Comment: How do you mean? I did divide it into smaller pieces - 1, 2, 3. And 2) is just the questions about syntax. I'm not sure if there are symbolic representations of functions in matlab

Comment: I meant: Ask 3 smaller questions.

Comment: ... are you serious? XD they are literally one sentence each XD plus one or two sentences elaborating ... I'm not sure how much smaller I can make them ...

Comment: Yes. This question has a close vote from someone (not me) that said "Unclear what is asked".

Comment: lol! Well I'm really not sure what's unclear here... so help me help you help me +) ... where does confusion lie?

Comment: The confusion is that you are asking three different things. 2. and 3. are easy to understand but make them two different question. If a person knows the answer to 2. he might not know the answer to 3 (and vice versa). Question 1 is unclear / too large. Can you give concrete examples in your question.

Comment: i guess i can do that ... i was trying not to spam up the feed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick way to do is use a package in Mathematica called [ToMatlab](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/) (I attached the download link). It is able to convert Mathematica symbol syntax to Matlab .m file.

Hope this would help.